# Should we recite a surah in the last two rakat

Tags: hadith, salat

Asalamualikum,

When praying a 4 rakat Salah, whether it is sunnah or fard, do we recite a surah after reciting Fatiha on the third and fourth rakat ?

Does this apply to all 4 rakat salah?

Comment: Welcome to [islam.se]. Please go through [this](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/a/107/3487).

Answer (score 2):

**Recitation of Aayaat after al-Faatihah in the last two Rak'ahs**

"He used to make the last two rak'ahs about half as long as the first two, about fifteen aayaat, and sometimes he would recite only al-Faatihah in them."

***Sometimes*** "he would let them hear an aayah or so."

"They would hear the tones of his recitation of "Glorify the name of your Lord Most High" (A'laa 87:19) and "Has the story reached you of the Overwhelming ?" (Ghaashiyah 88:26)."

***Sometimes*** "he would recite "By the Sky and the Night-Visitant" (Taariq, 86:17), "By the Sky, (displaying) the Constellations" (Burooj, 85:22), and similar soorahs."
Sometimes "he would recite "By the Night as it conceals" (Layl 92:21) and similar soorahs."

Therefore, the above indicates that it would be Sunnah to recite as well as not.

```
                                    And Allah knows the best
```

The Prophet's Prayer -Shaikh Al-Albani